# Include Quotation in string, but without the escape character

Tags: c#

I've just posted before (related, but not the same question).

So I'm working on an email button in c# in an application I use, and I'm currently trying to pass multiple email addresses into mailMsg.To.Add(emailAddress).

The string in emailAddress will be email addresses separated by a ;. The method mailMsg.To.Add takes email addresses in the form "email@test.co.uk" + "email2@test.co.uk". I've managed to split and join the email addresses with quotations at the start and end, but inbetween the addresses, I can't seem to get " + " in there (to make "email@test.co.uk" + "email2@test.co.uk").

Whenever I try to include the quotation marks in my string.Join, it always includes the escape character.

```
string strQuote = ;

        string[] emails = SessionEmail.Split(';');
        gblTeacherEmail = string.Join((strQuote + " + " + strQuote),emails);
```

So in strQuote, I've tried @""""; but this gives \" at the end of the email address. I've also tried "\""; but this gives the same result.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

edit: I'll include an example.

So if SessionEmail = "email1@test.co.uk;email2@test.co.uk";
string strQuote = @"""";
Then
string[] emails = SessionEmail.Split(';');
gblEmails = string.Join((strQuote + " + " strQuote), emails);

This gives the output as
SessionEmail = "email1@test.co.uk\" + \"email2@test.co.uk";

The same happens if strQuote = "\"";

Comment: A short but complete example demonstrating the problem would *really* help here. It's not clear from the question which quotes are meant to show the string start/end, and which are really meant to be in the string.

Comment: Could it be that the Visual Studio viewers and watches show you \", but that you string value does not actually contain the backslash character? Can you include the code you use to validate the contents of your result? Like "Console.Write(emails)"?

Comment: It does, as I'm trying to pass these emails into mailMsg.To.Add() and this throws an exception "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address". Under locals, the string is showing as what I've put above in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class and just want to add multiple email addresses to the To method, you need to pass them with the format:

"email1@test.co.uk,email2@test.co.uk"

So in your specific case you would just need to replace the ";" with ","

Check [MailAddressCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Worked perfectly - just changed the seperator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted solution works (using commas to delimitate the email addresses), I'd say that's not the "right way" to add many recipients to an e-mail message. If you check the [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) you will see that, although the comma is not in the supported character list for the local part of e-mail addresses, it is allowed if the local part is a quoted string... so although not recommended (even by the RFCs), `"My,Email"@myhost.com` is a perfectly legal email address, and would break the solution.

So the "right way" is adding each recipient to the `To` collection (by means of strings or `MailAddress` instances).

So in your case, if there's an absolute need that the source input is a semicolon-separated string (which is also a bad idea), I'd do something like:

```
var emails = SessionEmail.Split(';').Select(x => new MailAddress(x));
mailMsg.To.AddRange(emails);
```

This is probably "over the top", since if anyone has a quoted-with-comma-email address, he deserves any mail client to crash, but just for "correctness". I myself have even implemented semicolon separated strings for multiple email addresses, but I *know* it's not the "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using a deprecated version of the mailMessage.To.Add() method. See: [System.Net.Mail and multiple TO recipients](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/573c5c98-112a-4ab7-adf6-8963c35e60f7/systemnetmail-and-multiple-to-recipients)

I know the question is how to get the quotes in there, but clearly the intent is to send to multiple recipients.  To do this you should add each email address as an instance of MailAddress. This will use the current method, not the original deprecated method, which should not be used.